# Magento 2: How can get value input with knockout Js?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, input

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test"/>
```

i want using ko get value of input. 
my component

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function(Component) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // component initialization logic
            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should use data-bind to get value in html

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="test2" data-bind="value: yourValue()"/>

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<input type="hidden" id="test" name="test"  data-bind="value: test">
```

Review https://mage2.pro/t/topic/597